# What is an inverse limit of codiscrete finite spaces?

Tags: general-topology, limits-colimits

If, instead of giving the discrete topology to finite sets $S_i$, I give them the indiscrete topology, (i.e. the only opens of $S_i$ are the empty set and $S_i$ itself), is it possible to take the inverse limit of such a (directed) system $\lbrace S_i\rbrace$?

If yes, what do I get?

Answer (score 2):

You get a subspace of the product space $\prod_iS_i$. The product of indiscrete spaces has the indiscrete topology, so every subspace has the indiscrete topology. Which subspace you get depends on your bonding maps.

Comment: Thanks, @brian. I wwas thinking about (co-) directed limits.In particular, what I was interested in when asked the question, was whether there is a known classification of such spaces, like there is for the inverse limits of discrete finite spaces (which are the compact Hausdorff tot. disc. spaces)